# Finding the biggest square in a rectangle with a condition

Tags: algorithm

In a rectangle with given height and width. I'm supposed to find the square with most 1s and print the number of 1s on stdout, also in that same square there must not be more 2s than half of 1s, i.e:**((# of 1s) /2) >= (# of 2s)**. 
Square is always at least 2x2 big.
So for the input (first two numbers are height and width):

```
6 8    
0 0 2 2 2 1 2 1
0 1 2 2 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 1 2 0 2
2 1 0 2 2 1 1 1
1 2 1 0 0 0 1 0
1 2 0 1 1 2 1 1
```

The correct answer is 9.(square is 5x5 big and the upperleft corner is on second row, third column)

Now i managed to somewhat write a program that does this correctly, but it's too slow.

So my I'm asking for an advice how to write the algorithm so that it solves this: https://justpaste.it/1cfem  under 1 second(correct answer 15) and this: https://justpaste.it/1cfen under 4 seconds(correct answer 556).

EDIT: I forgot to mention by square I mean only the perimeter of the square (the four sides)

My code works something like this:
Iterate trough all the fields in the input and iterate trough all the possible squares that start in this field(starting from the biggest square possible). Then I have some conditions like that I break the iteration when the possible perimeter of the square is smaller than the already biggest number of 1s i have found so far in a perimete etc. Also when I'm trying to find the squares starting from the given field, I remember the up side and left side of the preceding square and then just decrement it(if there is a 1 or 2).

But this isn't enough, since solution like this solves the second input in like 1 and a half minute a I need it in four seconds.
The code:
NOTE: the minerals represent 1s and toxics represent 2s

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int maxMinerals;

void traverseforH(const int const *map, const int height, const int width) {
    const int h1 = height - 1;
    const int w1 = width - 1;
    int lineOffset = 0;
    for (int startY = 0; startY < h1; startY++) {
        int yside = height - startY;
        if (!(yside * 2 + (yside - 2)*2 > maxMinerals)) {
            break;
        }
        for (int startX = 0; startX < w1; startX++) {
            int xside = width - startX;
            if (!(xside * 2 + (xside - 2)*2 > maxMinerals)) {
                break;
            }        
            int maxBoundl = width;
            int maxBoundm = width;
            if (startY + maxBoundm - height - startX > 0) {
                maxBoundl = height;
                maxBoundm = height;
                if (startX - startY > 0) {
                    maxBoundl = maxBoundl + startY - startX;
                } else {
                    maxBoundm = maxBoundm + startX - startY;
                }
            } else if (startY - startX > 0) {
                maxBoundm = maxBoundm + startY - startX;
                maxBoundl = maxBoundm;
                maxBoundm = maxBoundm + startX - startY;
            } else {
                maxBoundl = maxBoundl + startY - startX;
            }
            int mBw = (maxBoundl - 1) * width;

            int toxicsLeftSide = 0;
            int mineralsLeftSide = 0;
            int toxicsUpSide = 0;
            int mineralsUpSide = 0;
            int mw;
            int lastMinerals = 0;
            int toxics = 0;
            int sidey = lineOffset + width;
            for (int x = startX; x < maxBoundm; x++) {
                mw = x + lineOffset;
                if (map[mw] == 1) {
                    mineralsUpSide++;
                    lastMinerals++;
                } else if (map[mw]) {
                    toxicsUpSide++;
                    toxics++;
                }
                mw = x + mBw;
                if (map[mw] == 1) {         
                    lastMinerals++;
                } else if (map[mw]) {
                    toxics++;
                }
            }
            for (int y = startY + 1; y < maxBoundl - 1; y++) {
                mw = startX + sidey;
                if (map[mw] == 1) {
                    mineralsLeftSide++;
                    lastMinerals++;
                } else if (map[mw]) {
                    toxicsLeftSide++;
                    toxics++;
                }
                mw = maxBoundm - 1 + sidey;
                if (map[mw] == 1) {
                    lastMinerals++;
                } else if (map[mw]) {
                    toxics++;
                }
                sidey = sidey + width;
            }
            if (map[startX + mBw] == 1) {
                mineralsLeftSide++;
            } else if (map[startX + mBw]) {
                toxicsLeftSide++;
            }

            int upsideData [2];
            upsideData[0] = mineralsUpSide;
            upsideData[1] = toxicsUpSide;

            if (!(lastMinerals / 2.0 < toxics) && lastMinerals > maxMinerals) {
                maxMinerals = lastMinerals;
            }
            mBw = mBw - width;
            int noOfSquares;
            if (xside < yside) {
                noOfSquares = xside - 1;
            } else {
                noOfSquares = yside - 1;
            }
            for (int k = 1; k < noOfSquares; k++) {
                int maxBoundy = maxBoundl - k;
                int maxBoundx = maxBoundm - k;
                if (!(((maxBoundx - startX)*2 + (maxBoundx - 2 - startX)*2) > maxMinerals)) {  
                    break;
                }
                sidey = lineOffset + width;
                lastMinerals = 0;
                toxics = 0;
                if (map[maxBoundx + lineOffset] == 1) {
                    mineralsUpSide--;
                } else if (map[maxBoundx + lineOffset]) {
                    toxicsUpSide--;
                }
                if (map[startX + mBw + width] == 1) {
                    mineralsLeftSide--;
                } else if (map[startX + mBw + width]) {
                    toxicsLeftSide--;
                }
                for (int x = startX + 1; x < maxBoundx; x++) {
                    mw = x + mBw;
                    if (map[mw] == 1) {
                        lastMinerals++;
                    } else if (map[mw]) {
                        toxics++;
                    }
                }
                for (int y = startY + 1; y < maxBoundy - 1; y++) {
                    mw = maxBoundx - 1 + sidey;
                    if (map[mw] == 1) {
                        lastMinerals++;
                    } else if (map[mw]) {
                        toxics++;
                    }
                    sidey = sidey + width;
                }
                int finalMinerals = lastMinerals + mineralsLeftSide + mineralsUpSide;
                int finalToxics = toxics + toxicsLeftSide + toxicsUpSide;
                if (!(finalMinerals / 2.0 < finalToxics) && finalMinerals > maxMinerals) {
                    maxMinerals = finalMinerals;
                }
                mBw = mBw - width;


            }

        }
        lineOffset = lineOffset + width;
    }
    printf("%d\n", maxMinerals);
}

void traverseforW(int *map, const int height, const int width) {
    int h1 = height - 1;
    int w1 = width - 1;
    int lineOffset = 0;
    for (int startY = 0; startY < h1; startY++) {
        int yside = height - startY;
        if (!(yside * 2 + (yside - 2)*2 > maxMinerals)) {
            break;
        }
        for (int startX = 0; startX < w1; startX++) {
            int xside = width - startX;
            if (!(xside * 2 + (xside - 2)*2 > maxMinerals)) {
                break;
            }
            int maxBoundl = height;
            int maxBoundm = height;
            if (startX + maxBoundl - width - startY > 0) {
                maxBoundl = width;
                maxBoundm = width;
                if (startX - startY > 0) {
                    maxBoundl = maxBoundl + startY - startX;
                } else {
                    maxBoundm = maxBoundm + startX - startY;
                }
            } else if (startY - startX > 0) {
                maxBoundm = maxBoundm + startX - startY;
            } else {
                maxBoundl = maxBoundl + startX - startY;
                maxBoundm = maxBoundl;
                maxBoundl = maxBoundl + startY - startX;
            }
            int mBw = (maxBoundl - 1) * width;

            int toxicsLeftSide = 0;
            int mineralsLeftSide = 0;
            int toxicsUpSide = 0;
            int mineralsUpSide = 0;
            int mw;
            int lastMinerals = 0;
            int toxics = 0;
            int sidey = lineOffset + width;
            for (int x = startX; x < maxBoundm; x++) {
                mw = x + lineOffset;
                if (map[mw] == 1) {
                    mineralsUpSide++;
                    lastMinerals++;
                } else if (map[mw]) {
                    toxicsUpSide++;
                    toxics++;
                }
                mw = x + mBw;
                if (map[mw] == 1) {            
                    lastMinerals++;
                } else if (map[mw]) {
                    toxics++;
                }
            }
            for (int y = startY + 1; y < maxBoundl - 1; y++) {
                mw = startX + sidey;
                if (map[mw] == 1) {
                    mineralsLeftSide++;
                    lastMinerals++;
                } else if (map[mw]) {
                    toxicsLeftSide++;
                    toxics++;
                }
                mw = maxBoundm - 1 + sidey;
                if (map[mw] == 1) {
                    lastMinerals++;
                } else if (map[mw]) {
                    toxics++;
                }
                sidey = sidey + width;
            }
            if (map[startX + mBw] == 1) {
                mineralsLeftSide++;
            } else if (map[startX + mBw]) {
                toxicsLeftSide++;
            }
            if (!(lastMinerals / 2.0 < toxics) && lastMinerals > maxMinerals) {
                maxMinerals = lastMinerals;
            }
            mBw = mBw - width;

            int noOfSquares;
            if (xside < yside) {
                noOfSquares = xside - 1;
            } else {
                noOfSquares = yside - 1;
            }
            for (int k = 1; k < noOfSquares; k++) {
                int maxBoundy = maxBoundl - k;
                int maxBoundx = maxBoundm - k;
                if (!(((maxBoundx - startX)*2 + (maxBoundx - 2 - startX)*2) > maxMinerals)) {    
                    break;
                }
                sidey = lineOffset + width;
                lastMinerals = 0;
                toxics = 0;
                if (map[maxBoundx + lineOffset] == 1) {
                    mineralsUpSide--;
                } else if (map[maxBoundx + lineOffset]) {
                    toxicsUpSide--;
                }
                if (map[startX + mBw + width] == 1) {
                    mineralsLeftSide--;
                } else if (map[startX + mBw + width]) {
                    toxicsLeftSide--;
                }
                int finalMinerals = mineralsUpSide + mineralsLeftSide;
                int finalToxics = toxicsLeftSide + toxicsUpSide;
                for (int x = startX + 1; x < maxBoundx; x++) {
                    mw = x + mBw;
                    if (map[mw] == 1) {
                        lastMinerals++;
                    } else if (map[mw]) {
                        toxics++;
                    }
                }
                for (int y = startY + 1; y < maxBoundy - 1; y++) {
                    mw = maxBoundx - 1 + sidey;
                    if (map[mw] == 1) {
                        lastMinerals++;
                    } else if (map[mw]) {
                        toxics++;
                    }
                    sidey = sidey + width;
                }
                finalMinerals += lastMinerals;
                finalToxics += toxics;
                if (!(finalMinerals / 2.0 < finalToxics) && finalMinerals > maxMinerals) {
                    maxMinerals = finalMinerals;
                }
                mBw = mBw - width;
            }
        }
        lineOffset = lineOffset + width;
    }
    printf("%d\n", maxMinerals);
}

int main() {
    char hw[14];
    FILE * file = fopen("pub01.in", "r");
    char c;
    int k = 0;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != '\n') {
        hw[k] = c;
        k++;
    }
    int h, w;
    sscanf(hw, "%d %d", &h, &w);
    int size = h * w;
    int* input = malloc(size * sizeof (int) + 1);
    k = 0;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2') {
            input[k] = c - '0';
            k++;
        }
    }
    input[k] = '\0';
    if (h > w) {
        traverseforH(input, h, w);
    } else {
        traverseforW(input, h, w);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preprocess step:**

First pre-process matrix, using prefix sum method all rows and columns so that you will be able to calculate # of 1s and # of 2s in the perimeter of square in O(1).

By now you will have 4 data-structures:  rowSumFor1, rowSumFor2, colSumFor1, colSumFor2. For example: rowSumFor1[i][j] would tell us # of 1s in ith row for column indices between 0 and j inclusive.

Time complexity: O(w x h)

**Complete Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>


int min(int a,int b){
    return (a<=b)?a:b;
}

int max(int a,int b){
    return (a>=b)?a:b;
}

// currently hard-coding dimensions for test purposes
// horizontal sums
int rowSumFor1[600][600];
int rowSumFor2[600][600];

// vertical sums
int colSumFor1[600][600];
int colSumFor2[600][600];

int main(){


    int w,h;

    scanf("%d %d",&h,&w);



    for(int row=1;row <= h;row++)for(int col=1;col <= w;col++){

        int temp;

        scanf("%d",&temp);

        // first add previous sum
        rowSumFor1[row][col]=rowSumFor1[row][col - 1];
        rowSumFor2[row][col]=rowSumFor2[row][col - 1];

        colSumFor1[col][row]=colSumFor1[col][row - 1];
        colSumFor2[col][row]=colSumFor2[col][row - 1];

        if(temp==1){
            rowSumFor1[row][col]++;
            colSumFor1[col][row]++;
        }
        else if(temp==2){
            rowSumFor2[row][col]++;
            colSumFor2[col][row]++;
        }
        else{
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    int result = 0,rowId,colId,mlength;

    for(int len=min(w,h); len > 1 ; len-- ) //  iteration on possible lengths
    {
       for(int row=1;row <= (h - len + 1);row++)for(int col=1;col <= (w - len + 1);col++){ // iteration on all co-ordinates as upper-left corner of our square

         // Do calculation here for properties and necessary checking constraints for validity of this square

         // Note: not checking trivial conditions like boundary conditions in square, you will have to!!

           // Beware of over-counting of corners here, one way to avoid is to select indices such that they don't overcount corners

           // 4x4 square example for counting
           // aaab
           // d  b
           // d  b
           // dccc

           int topEdge1 = rowSumFor1[row][col + len - 2] - rowSumFor1[row][col - 1];
           int bottomEdge1 = rowSumFor1[row + len - 1][col + len - 1] - rowSumFor1[row + len - 1][col];
           int leftEdge1 = colSumFor1[col][row + len - 1] - colSumFor1[col][row];
           int rightEdge1 = colSumFor1[col + len - 1][row + len - 2] - colSumFor1[col + len - 1][row - 1];

           int ones= topEdge1 + bottomEdge1 + leftEdge1 + rightEdge1; // # of 1s on perimeter of this square 



           int topEdge2 = rowSumFor2[row][col + len - 2] - rowSumFor2[row][col-1];
           int bottomEdge2 = rowSumFor2[row+len-1][col+len-1] - rowSumFor2[row+len-1][col];
           int leftEdge2 = colSumFor2[col][row + len - 1] - colSumFor2[col][row];
           int rightEdge2 = colSumFor2[col + len - 1][row + len - 2] - colSumFor2[col + len -1][row - 1];

           int twos= topEdge2 + bottomEdge2 + leftEdge2 + rightEdge2; // # of 2s on perimeter of this square 


           if(ones >= 2* twos){
                if(ones > result){
                    result = ones;
                    rowId = row;
                    colId = col;
                    mlength = len;
                }
           }
       }

    }

    printf("%d %d %d\n",rowId,colId,mlength);
    printf("%d\n",result);

    return 0;
}
```

Time complexity: O(w x h x min(w,h))

**EDIT:**

Replaced pseudo-code with complete code. It results as expected for all 3 tests presented by OP.

Comment: Happy to help :D